# IE6 prototype.js/window.js rendering issue

Tags: css, iframe, html, internet-explorer-6

Has anyone else ran into the issue where you created a prototype based window using the window.js library and it renders just fine in every browser except IE6?

The test page I am trying to use to debug this issue can be viewed at rik.kmshooting.com/test.php

As you can see, the window graphics, which are background-image values assign in CSS are obviously being wiped out in IE6. I have tried the examples given on the website that actually developed this and it seems to do the same thing there.

I would love it if someone has come up with an answer or good workaround for this issue.

Thanks folks.

~A~

Comment: You're using HTTP AUTH on your testpage. don't know if we're supposed to guess the username and password, or if you just wanted to tell us that you had a test page? ;)

Comment: rik.kmshooting.com/test.php requires authentication

Comment: Ooops...sorry, sorta forgot I had that enabled. It's been temporarily disabled for your folks to get a look at.

Comment: Well...I can't use that page as my example as I also have been making changes to it now. So, thank you anyway for the attempted efforts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your particular case, but I have had instances of CSS backgrounds not appearing in modal dialogs on IE6. Pre-loading the image when the page loads using JavaScript solved this issue:

```
tmpImg = new Image()
tmpimg.src ="image/bg1.gif"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a server side fix for flickering background images in IE6.

Add an HTTP header, something like Cache-Control: post-check=3600,pre-check=43200

This page is for IIS but some people mention Apache in the comments:
http://aspnetresources.com/blog/cache_control_extensions.aspx